# How can I make my script wait for jQuery animate to finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I've got a function called runUpdates that I pass an array of JSON objects to. This function looks through the objects and has if statements to decide what kind of update it is and which direction it should take to process that update. In some situations the update has an animation tied to it. I want to use jQuery's animate to animate these but I want it to wait for the animation to finish before it proceeds to the next step.

My program looks something like this-

```
runUpdates(updates) {
    for(i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
        update = updates[i];
        if(update.type = "blabla") {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
            if(update.animations) {
                for(k = 0; k < animations.length; k++) {
                    //do jquery animate AND wait for animation to finish before proceeding
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the script will continue running even after the animation has started. Is there a simple way to fix this or am I going to need to reinvent the loop with function calls?

Comment: does the animation have animation end event?

Comment: I suspect you will have to restructure the loop to use function calls. jQuery's `.animate()` has a complete callback that you can use to kick off the next step in your process.

Comment: *looks something like this* - why not show us some **real** code?!

Answer (score 3):

You weren't very clear in your question what it is you want to wait for. I'm assuming you want to wait for each animation to complete before continuing to the next one.

```
var pipe = $.Deferred().resolve();

for(var k = 0; k < animations.length; k++)
{
    pipe = pipe.pipe(function()
    {
        return $('element').animate({
            // animate whatever you want
        }, 300);
    });
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyS6c/

---

If you then want to run some code after all the animations have completed, put it in a `done` function:

```
pipe.done(function()
{
    // Put your code here...
});
```

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyS6c/1/

---

If you're not interested in chaining the animations (you want them to execute asynchronously), and only want to run some code after all the animations have completed, use this:

```
var deferreds = [];

for(var k = 0; k < animations.length; k++)
{
    deferreds.push(
        $('element').animate({
            // animate whatever you want
        }, 300)
    );
}

$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function()
{
    // Put your code here...
});
```

...and finally, here's the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/pdDME/

Comment: Instead of chaining all animation promises with `pipe`, the more natural way is to wait on multiple promises with `jQuery.when`.

Comment: @Ates Goral - Can you please edit my fiddle and post a link here? I'm not sure I'm following you. How would you implement this with `when`?

Answer (score 1):

First you can use jQuery's animation callback - http://jsfiddle.net/zutBh/1/.

Second there is a [jQuery.deffereds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.